# Yammer - Group Membership REST Endpoints?

Tags: yammer

I've been using the https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits to query messages and users of my group. I discovered that there are undocumented 'group' endpoints

1. https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/xxx.json
2. https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/xxx/members.json

In my case, the group request says that I have 60 members in the group, but when I query the 'group_members' endpoint, I only get a list of 50 users. I appreciate this is an attempt by yammer to trottle the amount of data returned, but is there a recommended workaround that will allow me to retrieve all 60 users via multiple calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'page'

```
?page=%page number%
```

attribute just like on any other endpoint.

However, I'd suggest to use the documented way as described here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesin_groupgroup_id

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/:group_id.json
```

It will also return the group members, allowing you to paginate results.